# How to enable NATO symbols in Wargame: Air Land Battle?

Tags: wargame-airland-battle

Since I liked playing Wargame: European Escalation, I recently bought Wargame: Air Land Battle. I  miss the NATO symbols though. Is there a way to enable them in the game?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, slightly hidden in the options: Go to `Options`->`Interface` (on the left side, not in the Gameplay window -> `Icons` in the center windows and change them from `RTS` to `NATO`.